# How to post-process other BeanPostProcessor-s in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, post-processing

I was thinking, that [`BeanPostProcessor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) should receive call for each bean in the context. Unfortunately, I found it is not true if other beans are postprocessors too.

The code follows:

```
public class MutualBeanPostProcessorTest {

   @Configuration
   public static class Config {

      @Bean
      public Bean0 bean0() {
         return new Bean0();
      }

      @Bean
      public Bean1 bean1() {
         return new Bean1();
      }

      @Bean
      public Bean2 bean2() {
         return new Bean2();
      }

      @Bean
      public Bean3 bean3() {
         return new Bean3();
      }
   }

   public static class Bean0  {
      {
         System.out.println("Constructor of " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
      }
   }

   public static class Bean1 implements BeanPostProcessor {
      {
         System.out.println("Constructor of " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
      }

      public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
         return bean;
      }

      public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
         System.out.println("Postprocessor Bean1 called for " + beanName);
         return bean;
      }
   }

   public static class Bean2 implements BeanPostProcessor {
      {
         System.out.println("Constructor of " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
      }

      public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
         return bean;
      }

      public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
         System.out.println("Postprocessor Bean2 called for " + beanName);
         return bean;
      }
   }

   public static class Bean3 {
      {
         System.out.println("Constructor of " + this.getClass().getSimpleName());
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
   }

}
```

Output follows:

```
Constructor of Bean2
Constructor of Bean1
Postprocessor Bean2 called for org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor
Postprocessor Bean1 called for org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor
Postprocessor Bean2 called for org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory
Postprocessor Bean1 called for org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory
Constructor of Bean3
Postprocessor Bean2 called for bean3
Postprocessor Bean1 called for bean3
Constructor of Bean0
Postprocessor Bean2 called for bean0
Postprocessor Bean1 called for bean0
```

I.e. neither postporcessor processes another one.

How to fix?

Comment: Could you post the code of your BeanPostProcessor?

Comment: I can't reproduce the situation yet. If I try, then I have postprocessor initialized first and I can't know, what happen if it would not.

Comment: I just wanted to take a look at the BeanPostProcessor implementation you have. No need for a reproducable error just yet. :)

Comment: Sorry, see my update then...

Comment: @GergelyBacso see my update now please, I found the reason but didn't found any solution yet

Comment: *"My BeanPostProcessor is initiated in the middle of context initialization, so it hears only beans, which got initialized after him."* - this one is explained in the Spring documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-extension

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out what is going on. Probably I would post more info about how the context is created, some of the regular beans, and everything about the PostProcessor.

Comment: Wait a sec. You are trying to apply a BeanPostProcessor on another BeanPostProcessor?

Comment: @GergelyBacso yes, this is what I found now.

Comment: I think you are working on the impossible then. It is like a chicken and egg problem. You want both of your BeanPostProcessors be called *before the other one got initialized*.